# Conflicto entre rutas en Laravel

Tags: laravel, web, rutas

Hola buen día tengo las siguientes rutas, al momento de acceder a la ruta 'roles/crear' esta se confunde con la ruta 'roles/{id}', ya que confunde la palabra 'crear' con el parámetro 'id', ¿De que manera puedo evitar que esto suceda?

[image: Rutas del proyecto]

Comment: Por favor, evita las imágenes. Puedes añadir el código como texto.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes poner la ruta que tiene en la uri `crear`, antes de la que tiene el parámetro `{id}`.

Pero si quieres no preocuparte con el orden, y estás usando como id `integers` o `bigIntegers` puedes agregarle a la ruta que tiene el parámetro `{id}` un regex como este:

```
->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Referencia:
Documentación Laravel Routing [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

Answer (score 0):

Debes intercambiar el orden de aparición de las rutas. Las rutas que contengan banderas, deben colocarse después de cualquier otra ruta que pueda disparar esa ambigüedad.

```
 Route::get('roles/{id}', ...
 Route::get('roles/crear', ...
```

En este primer caso, se interpreta siempre el segundo segmento como un Id. La segunda ruta no funcionará.

Sin embargo,

```
  Route::get('roles/crear', ...
  Route::get('roles/{id}', ...
```

Interpreta el segundo segmento como un Id, mientras no sea 'crear'. Funcionará como esperas. La ruta con la variable, colócala siempre de última.